# How to load in Tbitmap a file that don't have any extension?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

Under android, when we select an image from the gallery, we don't receive a filename with extension but an uri instead and we must use contentprovider to copy the file in one of our local directory.

Now as the file don't have any extension, how to load it in a Tbitmap object ? I try but i receive an error: can not load the image.

Comment: What about TBitmap.CreateFromFile? It looks internally for different signatures (gif, bmp, png, tiff, jpg), then loads and converts the file format accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

ok i did like this :

```
function  DetectImageExtension(const aFileName: string): String;
var aFileStream: TFileStream;
    aFirstBytes: Tbytes;
begin
  aFileStream := TFileStream.Create(aFileName, fmOpenRead);
  try
    if aFileStream.Size < 8 then exit('');
    SetLength(aFirstBytes, 8);
    aFileStream.ReadBuffer(aFirstBytes[0], length(aFirstBytes));
    if (aFirstBytes[0] = $FF) and
       (aFirstBytes[1] = $D8) then result := 'jpg'  // ÿØ
    else if (aFirstBytes[0] = $89) and
            (aFirstBytes[1] = $50) and
            (aFirstBytes[2] = $4E) and
            (aFirstBytes[3] = $47) and
            (aFirstBytes[4] = $0D) and
            (aFirstBytes[5] = $0A) and
            (aFirstBytes[6] = $1A ) and
            (aFirstBytes[7] = $0A) then result := 'png' // .PNG....
    else if (aFirstBytes[0] = $47) and
            (aFirstBytes[1] = $49) and
            (aFirstBytes[2] = $46) then result := 'gif' // GIF
    else if (aFirstBytes[0] = $42) and
            (aFirstBytes[1] = $4D) then result := 'bmp' // BM
    else result := '';
  finally
    aFileStream.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: I guess that comparing constant header byte array by `CompareMem` could work as well (lazy to start my virtual machine to verify on FMX though). The idea is that you declare fixed header byte arrays with their lengths to compare and detect with less code.